# Why can't I assign properties directly into my data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't access my question props to assign its property directly into my data properties. Using the property directly from my template works, but can't assign the property into the data.

I can only access the value of props from my template:

```
props: ['question'],
data () {
    return {

    }
};

computed: {
    upVote () {
        return this.question.upvoted
    },

    count () {
        return this.question.vote_count
    }
}

methods: {
    upVoteIt () {
        if(User.loggedIn()) {
            this.upVote = !this.upVote
            this.upVote ? this.incr() : this.decr()
        }
    },

    incr () {
        this.count ++
    },

    decr () {
        this.count --
    }
}

<v-icon size="50" :color="upcolor" @click="upVoteIt">fas fa-sort-up</v-icon>
<span> {{ count }} </span>
```

I get the value if I use the props directly inside my template instead of reassigning into the data property.

Comment: Where come from your question property ? Is it asynchrone ?

Comment: It comes from a resource API of question and i don't know it is asynchronous or not.

Comment: Well, if it's fetched from an API, it is possible that it is asynchrone. If it is case, your data could be initialized with wrong value (undefined or null). But your props are updated by the component parents that I guess, fetch data. Could you use computed instead data in order to validate that ?

Comment: yes it works with computed but i want to access its value to change like increase or decrease the count

Comment: There are several solutions, can you update your question and add your parent component ?

Comment: so i write functions to access computed properties and it tells me no setter for this property

Answer (score 0):

You can use .sync modifier. It is a special feature that you can use when you want synchronize props with your parent component : Here is the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) . you will no longer use the data.

So how it works, you need in your child compoment emit an event update question with the updated value :

```
props: ['question'],
methods: {
    upVoteIt () {
        if(User.loggedIn()) {
            this.$emit('update:question', {
               ...this.question,
               upvoted: !this.question.upvoted,
               count: this.question.upvoted ? this.question.count - 1 : this.question.count + 1 
            }
        }
    }
}

<v-icon size="50" :color="upcolor" 
    @click="upVoteIt">fas fa-sort-up</v-icon>
    <span> {{ question.vote_count }} </span>
```

Now in your parent you need to do something like this :

```
<YourQuestionComponent 
   :question.sync="myQuestionVariable"
/>
```

Comment: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "question" / this is the error message from upVoteIt function, how can i solve this?.